# RadioKit Alternative For Live Streaming Audio From URL

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, audio, audio-streaming

I was doing some reading up on [RadioKit](http://www.stormyprods.com/products/radiokit.php)

I like what they use, and it works well for my ShoutCast stream, but the price of it is a bit more than I can really do ($99) per app.  Are there any good tutorials for setting up a simple stream from URL player that can pause, rewind, and display what file is currently playing on the stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look at this site..

http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/revisiting-old-post-streaming-and.html

Its a bit old, but it should atleast get you up and started